# R Shiny on Remote Desktop (Windows Server 2019)

Tags: r, shiny, windows-server-2019

I would like to write and run Shiny apps using Remote Desktop on Windows Server 2019. This is normally possible without any issues - you can test it on VM remote server (as I did). However in my real world case running shiny app:

```
runApp(path,port=open_port)
```

where *open_port* is open port number, results in

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:open_port
```

and blank page:

[image]

As far as I can recognise running app does not result in having port open and listening i.e. I have checked in cmd using:

```
netstat -na | find "open_port"
```

that there is no activity on the port. Therefore it seems that something is blocking shiny from running the app. As mentioned before this is not a case if you try do in on clean Windows Server 2019 installation. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: There are a few things one could attempt for debugging the issue : 1) Check the console in the browser for any error messages. 2)
Add the `host = '0.0.0.0'` argument: `runApp(host = '0.0.0.0', path, port = open_port)`
and test if `servr::httd(port = open_port)` shows you an index of files.

Comment: `host = '0.0.0.0'` has the same result as described in the question. `servr` shows in the console that is started server on localhost, however it results either in blank page in Rstudio viewer or "cannot make a connection" in firefox or "this site is unaviable" in chrome

Comment: ok, and can you see any error messages in the browser console (F12 -> Console)?

Comment: the console is clear (browser is not rendering antyhing as it fails to make the connection). abovementioned works flawlessly on local station (i.e. using servr and seeing index of files) but does not on RDP.

Comment: Where is your RDP hosting? Do you have full admin of the system and can figure out if there is any Windows policy prevent R Shiny to open port?

Comment: Yes, we have an ability to change policies and so on. The problem is that we cannot identify what may be blocking R from starting servers (it is not only shiny problem, servr, Rook does not work as well).